# how does magento generate the content of store link (block name=store.links )in the mobile view

Tags: magento2, theme

in file **/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**, there is a block name **store.links** nested inside **navigation.sections**, which is used for the mobile view to show those account links. Can any one tell me how does those links are generated?

I have this question because I wrapped the **header.links** (account links) into my new block and move it from its original place of **header.panel** into **header-wrapper** (the one container the logo and search box originally). After changes, i noticed those links which should show under the **navigation.sections** ( tab name = Account), are not more showing. Any idea or direction i have to look in? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

here is my answer and hope can be a little help for those who are new to magento2.

> //vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/theme.js

there is a line

> $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\.links');

if .header.links is moved to block other than .panel.header or even is wrapped in a new div, the above line is required to be updated to. for my case, it should be like

> $('.header.content >.star-customer-login-links >
>   .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\.links');

This is the solution for this issue. but there may be another place have to be updated too. it's

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/navigation-menu.js

Comment: thx very much, you  SAVE ME! in my magento 2.0.2 the line is `$('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');`. Do you know why they use \\? I understood that it was a javascript trick, but i searched always for "store.links"! :(

Comment: sorry, i don't know the purpose of double backward slash neither. Btw, there are double slash in my 2.0.4 installation. it's the copy and paste mistake in my answer.

Comment: This works when user is not logged in. But breaks after logging in. Anything I am missing? I did change in the navigation-menu.js but no luck. Can you please tell me the exact place to change the class?

Comment: @LucScu: `#store.links` is an element id. However in a CSS selector the dot (`.`) is used to denote a class selector. If you were to write `#store.links` in CSS you would select an element with id `store` and a class `links`. Instead you want an element with id `store.links` so the selector would be `#store\.links` (i.e. the dot is escaped). Since this selector is inside a javascript string literal and backslash is a special character for javascript, it has to be escaped as well, thus the double backslash.

Comment: Thx you very much, is it clear

Comment: I am facing same issue on M2.3.3 But there is no files theme.js , i found navigation-menu.js can you please tell how can i fix the same

Comment: @VinitKumar Pretty sure you found it already but if anybody is wondering, the file is located in /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js